# Not getting the complete Subscriptions list

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

When i try to retrieve a list of all my subscribers, i only get 14 out of 33.

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/subscriptions?part=subscriberSnippet&maxResults=50&mySubscribers=true&order=alphabetical&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

If i reduce maxResults to 15, i get several pages but only duplicates filling the pages.

I have tested it here: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/subscriptions/list

What can i do? Is it a bug?

Comment: Do you get a full list of your subscribers when you remove the `order=alphabetical` parameter?

Comment: no, unfortunately not